# Convert 18 digit ID to 15 digit ID in Excel

Tags: excel

**Immediate Requirement**
Plz give approaches

I have Exported Account object records using DataLoader. ID's in the csv(Excel) file have (a0r90000008cJzaAAE) 18 digit.But i want those as (a0r90000008cJza)15 digit in the same sheet or other Excel Sheet.

I write formula `=LEFT(A2,15)`, it was truncated but when i tried to copy those cell to other Excel sheet It's getting nothing like blank because it was a formula cell.

What to do?

Plz tell me approaches

Comment: When you paste in Excel, just make sure to not paste the formula,, but instead the value only. I think it's CTRL+ALT+V instead of CTRL+V

Answer (score 0):

These two short macros will quickly peel off the 15 left-most characters from column A into either a newly inserted column B or directly into the original column A cells.

```
Sub keep_first_15()
    With Sheet1   '<-imported CSV files almost always have Sheet1 as their codename
        With .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(15, 9))
        End With
    End With
End Sub

Sub send_first_15_to_B()
    With Sheet1   '<-imported CSV files almost always have Sheet1 as their codename
        .Columns(2).Insert
        With .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1, 2), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                           FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(15, 9))
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

If you prefer to send the content to another worksheet, more information needs to be provided.